# Slideshow with 2 images sizes (landscape and portrait)

Tags: jquery, css, image-size

I'm using a slideshow on my website.
I need to display 2 types of images formats, one landscape (400/300) and the other portrait (300/400) (ratio 4/3).

I want the slideshow to be responsive, but with a max-height. When image is lanscape, full width, and when image is portait max-height and width auto.

Here is my CSS:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:300px;
}

.cycle-slideshow {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
    width:100%;height:auto;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="custom-pager"></div>

        <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=fade
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-auto-height=container
    data-cycle-pager="#custom-pager"
    data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#> {{slideNum}} </a>"

    >
    <img src="http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/6001_7000/6410.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.williamcronon.net/researching/photoimages/932_photographic_images_fig01_lowres.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.jesuites.com/v3/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/montagnes_rocheuses.jpg?9d7bd4">
    <img src="http://www.2tout2rien.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/images-les-plus-vues-de-2013-google-trends-27.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/zyhrK/73/ you can see on this example that image 3 and 4, which are in portrait format are too height and stretched to a 100% width, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a class `.landscape` and a class `.portrait` to specify the exact height and widths. Else use the container's size to maintain the images 3:4 ratio, don't touch the images style. All I did was change:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:300px;
}

.cycle-slideshow {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
    width:100%;height:auto;
}
```

To:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    max-height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    clear: both;
}
```

And it looks like both 1 and 2 maintain the 400 x 300 and 3 and 4 maintain the 300 x 400

Comment: thanks for your reply, but now my slideshow is not responsive anymore... any thoughts ?

Comment: I used the  http://jsfiddle.net/zyhrK/73/ link you sent me and simply copy and pasted the `.cycle-slideshow{` code over what was previously there and it worked fine. Did you change anything else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think this should do what you are after:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:300px;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    /* If you want the images centred then you will need the below css too */ 
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

and the html is the same but without the data-cycle-auto-height property:

```
<div id="custom-pager"></div>

        <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=fade
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-pager="#custom-pager"
    data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#> {{slideNum}} </a>"

    >
    <img src="http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/6001_7000/6410.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.williamcronon.net/researching/photoimages/932_photographic_images_fig01_lowres.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.jesuites.com/v3/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/montagnes_rocheuses.jpg?9d7bd4">
    <img src="http://www.2tout2rien.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/images-les-plus-vues-de-2013-google-trends-27.jpg">
</div>
```